# Vectorize python function

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, apply

I have an old function named `old_func` that takes as input two positional arguments, `x` and `y`. The input of the function was written like this using a tuple as the input:

```
def old_func(position):

    x, y = position 
    return x**2 + y**2
```

I now want a quick and easy way of calling the function over a grid of values:

```
xx = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 100)
yy = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 100)
X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xx, yy)

array_positions = (X,Y)
old_fun(array_positions)
```

The intent is that each operation on `x` in the function is done on all of the `X` and the same for `y`. I tried vectorizing the function using [`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) but that does not work. I prefer not to change the function to accept NumPy arrays because that will take too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below does the trick and saves you the trouble of creating `array_positions`.

---

First, use [`ravel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) to flatten `X` and `Y` into NumPy arrays of shape `(10000,)`.

```
X_flattened = X.ravel()
Y_flattened = Y.ravel()
```

Then, use [`apply_along_axis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) to implement the custom function iteratively down the length of these flattened arrays.

```
float_array = np.apply_along_axis(old_func, 0, (X_flattened, Y_flattened))
```

Finally, reshape the output array into the desired shape of `(100, 100)`.

```
np.reshape(float_array, (100, 100))
```

Comment: Thanks I think you are right, however since my `old_func` function is technically a function of one single tuple I would need `np.apply_along_axis(old_func, 0, (X_flattened, Y_flattened))` right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct! I modified the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Your own code should (and does) work fine:

```
def old_fun(position):

    x, y = position 
    z = x**2 + y**2
    return z

xx = numpy.linspace(0,1,100)
yy = numpy.linspace(0,1,100)
X,Y = numpy.meshgrid(xx, yy)

array_positions = (X,Y)
Z = old_fun(array_positions)
```

`Z.shape` is now `(100, 100)`.

In general, numpy arrays will work with any standard operator, like `+` and `**`. Note that although your `old_fun` takes a tuple as input, and this tuple needs to consist of two values, the type of the two values can be anything, as long as this type supports math operators. Both standard Python scalars and numpy arrays support these, so the code works fine.

A note about @JuanManuel's answer: although it works perfectly fine as well, `apply_along_axis` is specifically **not meant for** vectorization in the sense that people usually want to use it, i.e. getting good performance out of numpy. `apply_along_axis` will result in a slow Python loop, not a fast C-loop like properly vectorized code will. Your own code uses proper vectorization, so use that instead.

Comment: You are right. Hmm I should have tested my example to make sure it actually gave the original error that my actual function did. I will try to edit my question.